# Hide URL Query Strings WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I would like to hide all the query strings after admin.php in my WordPress such as `admin.php?page=wpforms-overview` so I would like to hide `?page=wpforms-overview`.

I tried using this

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /admin\.php\?page=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R]
```

but it didn't work.

I want my URL's to be http://example.com/dashboard/admin.php with no query params

Comment: Just FYI if admin.php is expecting to receive the page parameter, removing it via rewrite may break things.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that we can hide URL parameters using PHP. But I can give you a  solution using jQuery, which might help you.

```
add_action('admin_footer', function() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, url);
</script>
<?php 
});
```

It will display the parameters (less than a second) until load the above scripts and start running.

Comment: Thank you, It works but only after the page is completely loaded, do we have any option that would help us to hide it from the start itself.

Comment: Also can we hide this in elementor plugin?

Comment: @AlfiyaHussaini 
Yes, that is what I've mentioned in my reply. You may try applying it in "admin_head" and make sure to run it as soon as the page loads but if there's a delay on the server side can't help as JS runs on the client side.
Sorry for the lateness, I did not notice your comments. :)